# debug java projects in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug java in visual studio code but when it runs it cannot find the separate Sensor.java file in the util folder that I have?

the structure is

```
src\main
  java\io\github\streaming
    test_1
      TestProgram.java
    util
      Sensor.java
```

my launch.json is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "io.github.streaming.test_1.TestProgram",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "build",                 
            "args": []                              
        }

    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

is there something else I need to add to launch?

Comment: I can't see any trace of `util.java` in the shown structure

Comment: sorry meant `Sensor.java` in util folder

Comment: do you mean you could not call Sensor.Class ?

Comment: I can help you if you share the source code on github

Comment: Is the problem that `TestProgram` makes uses of `Sensor` and the former cannot find the latter? Maybe you forgot 'import java.io.github.streaming.util.Sensor` in `TestProgram`?